# How to get past three months sales continuously?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have sales data, I need to filter who(Agent id) is done more sales end of the last 3 days of the month, did more than 80 % sales (last three days sales/ Total sale particular month ), and continuously did the past three months.

I tried the below query it satisfies only the last three days sales more than the rest of the days and more than 80% sales that particular month((last three days sales/ Total sale particular month) . But I couldn't get who is done continuously for three months.

Example: One Agent, he did sales last 3 days sales more compare to the rest day sales and more than 80% sales in the last three days July and continuously did past three months (July, June, May)

```
SELECT   a.agent_id,a.agent_name,a.ivr_registered_district,s.agent_type,s.district,s.province,a.parent_level1_id,a.parent_level1,a.sales_channel,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
         COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date < TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS not_last_5days_sale_count,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS last_5days_sale_count,
       
        COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) /  
      ( COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date < TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) +
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       )) as percentage
FROM   EDW_TGT.FACT_LTE_SALES_CHANNELS a
JOIN SFA.sfa_agent_dtl s
ON a.agent_id = s.agent_id
where a.pre_post = 'LTE-PREPAID' and a.sales_channel in ('BUSINESS PARTNER', 'INSTITUSIONAL', 'REGIONAL TRADE PARTNERS', 'DISTRIBUTOR')
     --and  a.connection_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-07-01 00:00:0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('2020-07-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
     and a.connection_date < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)
GROUP BY a.agent_id,a.agent_name,a.ivr_registered_district,s.agent_type,s.district,s.province,a.parent_level1_id,a.parent_level1,a.sales_channel,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY')
HAVING COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date > TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END ) >
        COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date < TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       )
        
       AND  
       
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) >=3
       
      AND

        COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) /  
      ( COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date < TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) +
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN a.connection_date >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( a.connection_date ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       )) > 0.79
```

Comment: As a side not `TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH')` is redundant in your case, just use `TO_CHAR(a.connection_date, 'MON-YYYY')` instead.

Comment: i need only the past three months(July, June, May), if run this code in September so it wants to show only who is done August, July, June more sales. here it filters the whole year.

Comment: @ORA_Dentist can u plz support this?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan do u have any idea to do above scenario?